# Migrating absence of metric query from Prometheus to vmalert/victoriametrics

Tags: victoriametrics

I am in process of migrating from Prometheus to victoriametrics and in old setup, Prometheus scrapes data at regular intervals and execute a rate query to find absence of a metrics(no data for metric). The rule is as follows:

```
  - alert: no_data_metric_alert
    expr: rate(site_result_time[3m]) == 0
    for: 5m
    labels:
      site_id: '{{$labels.site_id}}_no_data_metric'
      alertType: No Data Alert
```

This works fine in current setup of Prometheus as even when there is no new data, the last know data is returned in every scrape, so the rate query works.

However when using **vmalert** with **victoriametrics**, the **rate **query is not working as there is no data for the metric and as vmalert uses instant queries.

I tried using **absent** and **absent_over_time** queries for vmalert, but in these case, the queries are not returning the series/labels, due to which I am not able to figure out which site has no data. Also tried **lag** and **count_over_time**. But none of these work when the data is absent for more than the duration as we get empty result.

Is there any alternate way or workaround to solve this using vmalert?

Answer (score 0):

> This works fine in current setup of Prometheus as even when there is no new data, the last know data is returned in every scrape, so the rate query works.

It works in the same way in VictoriaMetrics - if metric gets updated regularly (on each scrape or push), the `rate` function will work as you expect. Here's [an example](https://play.victoriametrics.com/select/accounting/1/6a716b0f-38bc-4856-90ce-448fd713e3fe/prometheus/graph/#/?g0.range_input=30m&g0.end_input=2023-08-07T09%3A14%3A40&g0.tab=0&g0.relative_time=last_30_minutes&g0.expr=rate%28disabled_metric_total%5B3m%5D%29+%3D%3D+0&g1.expr=disabled_metric_total&g1.range_input=30m&g1.end_input=2023-08-07T09%3A14%3A40&g1.tab=0&g1.relative_time=last_30_minutes) from the playground for a counter metric that doesn't grow but still gets regularly scraped.

> However when using vmalert with victoriametrics, the **rate **query is not working as there is no data for the metric and as vmalert uses instant queries.

It is likely data is indeed missing, not delivered to VictoriaMetrics for some reason. Could you elaborate more on how you get your data collected? It is also quite strange alerting rule: could you elaborate more on the logic of site_result_time metric change?

> I tried using absent and absent_over_time queries for vmalert

This approach works only if you exactly know which metric you're expecting to be missing - see [this article](https://www.robustperception.io/absent-alerting-for-jobs/) for details.

> Is there any alternate way or workaround to solve this using vmalert?

The mentioned alerting expression will work only if 2 following conditions are true:

1. site_result_time metric exists and the last recorded data sample is not older than at least 3min. Please note, that VictoriaMetrics by default looks for x2 of scrape_interval in the past, while Prometheus looks always for 5min in the past. You can achieve the same behavior by setting `-search.minStalenessInterval=5m` cmd-line flag for VictoriaMetrics.
2. rate(site_result_time[3m]) is indeed equal to 0. Which is quite awkward to get rate from time metric.